# Function applied to too many arguments error

Tags: haskell

When I try to compile the following code:

```
matcHelp :: String -> Stack Char -> Stack Char
matcHelp b = mtHelp b (MakeS([])) (MakeS([])) where 
                      mtHelp b result1 result2 =
                          if (b == [])
                              then result1 result2
                          else if head b == '('
                              then mtHelp (tail b) (push '(' result1) (result2)
                          else if head b == '['
                              then mtHelp (tail b) (result1) (push '[' result2)
                          else if (head b == ')')
                              then mtHelp (tail b) (popOut result1) (result2)
                          else if (head b == ']')
                              then mtHelp (tail b) (result1) (popOut result2)
                          else mtHelp (tail b) (result1) (result2)
```

I get that the function push:

```
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x (MakeS(xs)) = MakeS(x:xs)
```

is applied to too many arguments, specifically in the instance `(push '(' result1)`. I don't see why?

The actual error I'm getting is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t1 -> t0' with actual type `Stack a0'
    In the return type of a call of `push'
    Probable cause: `push' is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of `mtHelp', namely `(push '(' result1)'
    In the expression: mtHelp (tail b) (push '(' result1) (result2)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Note: 
MakeS is a data constructor

```
newtype Stack a = MakeS([a]) deriving Show
```

Comment: What is `MakeS`? Also what is the function type of `mtHelp`?

Comment: mtHelp is just a recursive helper function define right in the main function. MakeS is the data constructor for the data type Stack a

Comment: Can I see the type of `mtHelp`, please?

Comment: line 5, `then result1 result2` looks incorrect. This is where it infers that `result1` is a function, and then it finds it incorrect in the next location where you use it.

Comment: @tarmil Ah right, I guess I can't output two different items at the same time which is what I was trying to do

Comment: @jefffery the type of mtHelp would be String -> Stack Char -> Stack Char -> Stack Char -> Stack Char, where it outputs two Stack Char items but as I said in reply to tarmil I don't think I can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the line

```
if (b == []) then result1 result2
```

implies `result1` is a function to be applied to `result2`. From your type signature, `matchHelp` is supposed to be returning a `Stack Char`, so you've made an error here.

From your comments it's clear that you want to return multiple values from `matchHelp`. In Haskell, **all** functions take *one* argument and return *one* result, always. Even a function like

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

takes one argument (an `Int`) and returns one result (a function `Int -> Int`). You could write the type signature like this:

```
(+) :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

but Haskell does this for you anyways. This is called "currying".

The Haskell way to return multiple values is to return a single tuple containing those values or a data structure that you've defined yourself.

Unrelated, your function is not very "Haskell-y" with all those `if .. then .. else` and `head/tail` when pattern matching and guards should be used instead. Here's the rewritten function with multiple return values in a tuple.

```
matchHelp :: String -> Stack Char -> (Stack Char, Stack Char)
matchHelp b = mtHelp b (MakeS []) (MakeS [])
    where mtHelp []     result1 result2 = (result1, result2)
          mtHelp (x:xs) result1 result2     
            | x == '('  = mtHelp xs (push '(' result1) (result2)
            | x == '['  = mtHelp xs (result1) (push '[' result2)
            | x == ')'  = mtHelp xs (popOut result1) (result2) 
            | x == ']'  = mtHelp xs (result1) (popOut result2)
            | otherwise = mtHelp xs result1 result2
```

Comment: I did exactly that and returned a tuple. Thanks.